# How to stop react-filepond from uploading files automatically?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

as soon as you drag and drop a file or browse to one, react-filepond uploads the file automatically,

how do I prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `instantUpload` props it's set to `true` by default.

`<FilePond instantUpload={false} />`